# Javascript ajax call not opening file returned from url that works when called from url

Tags: javascript, php

I have a file that generates **excel** invoice. It's named view_porder.php.
It downloads and **excel** invoice.
However I want to call the `url` from Javascript. At that moment it doesn't download the excel file.
Please kindly help.

Here is the javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "../view_porder.php",
    data:{pdf:pid,order_id:id},
    success: function(res){
        window.location = url;
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems Like path issue. Try to provide full or relative path there. (check browser console and network tab that what URL hit by your ajax call and is it hitting the proper URL or not? )

Comment: Also let us know what errors you see in your browser console tab, when this ajax get hit?

Comment: Where did `url` came from? Because I think you should be using `window.location.href = res`

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes Url was the problem. I added the complete url and its now working. Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 1):

Please try using the full path. If that works, the relative path is causing the issue. Another thing you need to consider is that the relative path is with relation to the page executing the script and not relative to the script path itself.

Comment: I don't think that you can't use a relative path. But the other part is definitely true and important.

Answer (score 0):

what does your function return?
I think is not Json. May be you can call direct with out ajax it's work for me on Django i'm just return

```
response = HttpResponse(excel_file,content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=MOM {0}.xlsx'.format(datetime)
return response
```